# open Lotus Notes and attache file from website

Tags: java, javascript, lotus-notes, email-attachments, opencmis

I want to do something like this:

1. click on a link or button on an website (especially on Alfresco Share)
2. the email client (IBM Notes) should be opened and automatically attach a document from the repository of Alfresco (document management system)

I can grab the document with java using cmis api. How can I open the email client and programatically attach the document by clicking on a link? Have you any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: because I am not familiar with XPages I am trying it with Java Web Start.

Comment: I can't provide a complete answer, but using the "notes" protocol for links will launch the Notes client if it's installed. You should be able to use that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does this also provides the ability to download the document and attach it to the email? I also tried it with the simple mailto: function in html, but this way the document is still not attachable. As I mentioned I can get the document with Apache OpenCMIS API in java.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to produce a specific "notes://" URL that links to an xpage to open in the Notes client (requiring Notes 8.5.1 or later I think), and includes an argument identifying the attachment. Xpages can include Java code, which you can use to extract the attachment id from the URL, retrieve the attachment from wherever it was uploaded to, and attach to some Notes document.

Comment: There is also the option of using JavaScript and ActiveX automation.  Here's an article that partially describes it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28104/Automate-Client-Lotus-Mail-using-JavaScript The article discusses using the Notes.NotesSession object which sends the email without bringing up the Notes UI, but the Notes.NotesUIWorkspace class is also accessible this way, and the NotesUI classes can be used to (kind of obviously) automate UI operations. The downside is that this requires setting security options in the browser to allow ActiveX operations.

Comment: Thanks for the great info! But the main problem I am facing is that the files I want to attach are on our Alfresco repository and not on the local computer. But thank you!